# searching file for last matching line, then put 3rd word of this line into a variable

Tags: bash, environment-variables, awk

i have a logfile, 
a script checks this log-file every hour
it shall pack the 3rd word of the last matching line into a variable but i didn't manage it to work yet ..

logfile:

```
2018-11-18 22:27:10 1542576430 c2- restarted=true
2018-11-19 00:14:34 1542582874 c2- restarted=true
```

search for last line with c2- and pack this line int variable "lastline"

```
lastline=$(tac $logfile | grep -m1 c2-)
```

now put the 3 string of this line into a variable:

```
last=$(awk '{print $3}' $lastline)
```

But that does not work ..

especially it does not work wenn i try:

```
lastline=$(tac $(awk '{print $3}' $lastline) | grep -m1 c2-)
```

So can anyone help me ???
at the moment i have absolutely no clue .. 
the output is always:

```
awk: cannot open 2018-11-19 (No such file or directory)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This doesn't do what you think:

```
awk '{print $3}' $lastline
```

The second parameter should be the file name, not the string to process. In bash, you can send a string to the standard input of a comment using the here-string:

```
awk '{print $3}' <<< "$lastline"
```

So, without the intermediate variable:

```
last=$(awk '{print $3}' <<< "$(tac "$logfile" | grep -m1 c2-)")
```